# How is the number of ring members selected?

Tags: monerod, ringct, ring-signatures, ringsize

How is the number of ring members signing a transaction selected? Is it selected randomly by the sender or is it defined by the Monero wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ring size is currently fixed to 11 (10 decoys).

It's defined at a protocol level, so no transaction will be accepted by the network from a wallet not sending transactions with ring size 11.

For reference, this was implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/5ffb2ff9b7c301eda5811a939c705f26627c4735#diff-1279d7b0ddc432573cd2bd8c6e632c1fR2761).

Credit to @dEBRUYNE♦ and @user36303 for spurring me on to finding it in the code!

Comment: Note that a static ring size of 11 is also enforced on the protocol level currently. Put differently, no other ring size value can be used.

Comment: You sure? I followed the discussions on this and I thought it ended up as a minimum, not fixed, but wallets could still add higher. Briefly looked at the code and also couldn't find it fixed at the protocol level either, only wallet level

Comment: Yes. I, alas, cannot find the relevant pull request either currently.

Comment: Theres a couple for the wallets and min set globally [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/e344d93ce706482fc55bb036051dc08da18fabbb/src/cryptonote_config.h#L141). So not fixed.

Comment: It is fixed (modulo special cases with unmixable inputs). See check_tx_inputs.

Comment: It's only fixed to a minimum.